# How to move-up/move-down a windows languages with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

my question is about this part of windows control panel:

[image: Control panel]

I want a command line or powershell code to move this languages up or down. I found only this part of documentation https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852115.aspx, but it was not very helpful because I have little experience with powershell. I managed to get the list of languages but I can't switch them anyway.

[image: Powershell output]

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.NET Framework [List(Of T) Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) could help. You can use [`Reverse()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0axc2h2.aspx) for this simple case as follows:

```
$OldList = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$OldList.Reverse()
Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList $OldList -Force
```

Works even in slightly more complex scenario:

```
PS D:\PShell> Get-WinUserLanguageList | `
                  Format-Table -Property Autonym, LocalizedName, InputMethodTips -AutoSize

Autonym                  LocalizedName            InputMethodTips               
-------                  -------------            ---------------               
English (United Kingdom) English (United Kingdom) {0809:00000809, 0809:00000405}
čeština                  Czech                    {0405:00000405, 0405:00020409}
Ελληνικά                 Greek                    {0408:00000408}               
русский                  Russian                  {0419:00000419}               
Türkçe                   Turkish                  {041F:0000041F, 041F:00000426}
eesti                    Estonian                 {0425:0000041B, 0425:0001041F}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK I managed to do this:

```
$list =  Get-WinUserLanguageList;

$tmp = $list[0];
$list[0] = $list[1];
$list[1] = $tmp

Set-WinUserLanguageList $list -Force -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

I created a script from this and it is working fine.